# How to set character length of TextField by deformatting the formatted number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I used the below code to set character lentgh to 17:

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
//    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    int limit = 16;
    switch (theTextField.tag) {
        case 10:
            NSLog(@"I m In 10");
            //To set maximum No.of Charaters.
            return !([theTextField.text length]>limit && [string length] > range.length);
            break;
        case 11:
            NSLog(@"I m In 11");
            //To set maximum No.of Charaters.
            return !([theTextField.text length]>limit && [string length] > range.length);
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"I m In default");
            break;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I am formatting the entered charaters in the `textfieldShouldEndEditing`,

For Example,
I entered `12345678912345678`, its limit up to 17 and its formatting to `12,345,678,912,345,678`
 and we again back to `TextField` and we edited to `12,345,678,912,345` then it considers `,` (comma) as one character, so length of the `TextField` increases.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
NSString *stringNumber = @"12,345,678,912,345";
NSUInteger length = [[stringNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] length];
NSLog(@"length: %lu", length);
```

NSLog output:

```
length: 14
```

Use a number formatter.

Example:

```
NSString *stringNumber = @"12,345,678,912,345";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:stringNumber];
NSLog(@"number: %@", number);
stringNumber = [number stringValue];
NSLog(@"stringNumber: %@", stringNumber);
```

NSLog output:

```
number: 12345678912345
stringNumber: 12345678912345
```

Comment: Its working but , if we enter 17 digits,the result number is increased to +1 or sometimes its decreases, For example, i entered 12345678912345678, then i got 12,345,678,912,345,678 and again edited to 12,345,678,912,345,679 then its result to 12,345,678,912,345,680

Comment: This is over thought, I will post a simpler solution later.